# Why is using information_schema too much slow?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

Here is my code:

```
// dbs size
$sql = 'SELECT table_schema DB_Name,
               Round(Sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 2) DB_Size_in_MB
        FROM  information_schema.tables
        GROUP BY table_schema';
$dbs_size = DB::select($sql);
```

Executing query above takes 6 sec. Why? And how can I make it faster?

Comment: Is your server slow? Is it under heavy load? Do other queries take this long?

Comment: I think it's an environment not a query problem

Comment: @tadman Yes exactly. The server I'm using it is busy kinda. But still I think executing that query is slow more than enough.

Comment: @GurV Ah ok. thank you

Comment: Calculating the table size may require the dust to settle on in-flight queries, which can take time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately access to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES is very slow by nature, especially when you have many tables, because the server has to open every single file to satisfy the query.

You can find more info on how to speed up your queries on information_schema in this blog post :
https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/12/23/solving-information_schema-slowness/

Hope it helps!

Comment: 8.0 will also speed things up.